# How to force relative paths in Android Lint baseline

Tags: android, android-lint

I'm attempting to create a baseline lint file for my Android project. I've got a block set up in my main module's build.gradle:

```
lintOptions {
    <some includes/excludes>

    baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")

    checkAllWarnings true
    warningsAsErrors true
    abortOnError false
}
```

I then create the baseline with `./gradlew lint<flavor/variant>` and have set up my unit test task to depend on lint.

However, this gives a baseline file that includes some absolute paths. The culprits seem to be either a) in a submodule (but only some submodules, not all), or b) in my local gradle cache. When I push the baseline to our CI, it comes up with a bunch of new warnings because the paths don't match exactly.

Some examples include:

```
<location
        file="/Users/.../android/<submodule>/src/main/res/values/strings.xml"
        line="4"
        column="13"/>

<location
        file="/Users/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.auto.value/auto-value/1.3/4961194f62915eb45e21940537d60ac53912c57d/auto-value-1.3.jar"/>
```

How do I force lint to create the baseline using relative paths?

Answer (score 4):

use own baseline.xml for each module. paths will be relative to module root directory.

**UPDATE**
try to use only one **baseline.xml** put put it to the root gradle project above modules like this

```
project/app/build.gradle
project/module1/build.gradle
project/build.gradle
project/lint-baseline.xml
```

in module's build.gradle use such snippet

```
lintOptions {
    baselineFile = rootProject.file('lint-baseline.xml')
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
use own baseline.xml for each module. paths will be relative to module root directory.
in module's build.gradle use such snippet

```
lintOptions {
    baselineFile = project.file('lint-baseline.xml')
    checkDependencies = false
}
```

Comment: That seems to fix problem a), but not problem b). I'm still getting errors originating in the gradle build cache

Comment: gradle build cache is located outside of your project. you can not use reletive paths for files, localted at build cache

Comment: this solution is incorrect. lint puts relative paths to files that are not located in current module

Comment: This unfortunately won't work in a project with multiple module, because lint will abort after creating a baseline, so I end up with the warnings from only one module in the baseline.

Comment: try the first solution but add `checkDependencies false` to your lintOptions

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the `absolutePaths` option on `LintConfig`?

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    absolutePaths false
  }
}
```